# C#, can I declare a List<MyInterface<T>> of type Interface which has a generic type T?

Tags: c#, list, generics, interface, generic-collections

I want to do something, that I've done in Java.
I have an interface with a generic type like:

```
interface IDAO<T>
{
   void Save(T data);
}
```

And I have two classes that implement this interface:

```
class BankAccountDAO : IDAO<BankAccount>
{
   public void Save(BankAccount data){...}
}

class CategoryDAO : IDAO<Category>
{
   public void Save(Category data) {...}
}
```

I need another class with a List which should be declare of type IDAO with generic type T so that I can add the concrete classes to this list like this:

```
class Manager
{
   private List<IDAO> daoList = new List<IDAO>(); // here is the error
   daoList.Add(new BankAccountDAO());
   daoList.Add(new CategoryDAO());

   public void myMethod(BankAccount b)
   {
      daoList.ElementAt(0).Save(b); // this should call the implemented Save() method of BankAccountDao
   }
}
```

I did this in Java for a project but when I try to do this in C# I get an error:

> CS0305  C# Using the generic type requires 1 type arguments

Is there any way I can do something like this?

Comment: It's because C# has real generics not fake one like Java so `IDAO<BankAccount>` and `IDAO<Category>` are different types

Comment: Why not dictionary? or somthing similar that DIs are using ... first register like `TypeFactory.Register<IDAO<BankAccount>, BankAccountDAO>()` or `TypeFactory.Register<IDAO<BankAccount>>(new BankAccountDAO())` then usage `TypeFactory.Resolve<IDAO<BankAccount>>().Save(new BankAccount { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a type parameter to `IDAO` in your `Manager` class; in order to do that, you need some type that unifies with `BankAccount` and `Category`; if possible, I'd declare an interface called `IBusinessObject` which `Category` and `BankAccount` implement:

```cs
class Manager
{
   private List<IDAO> daoList = new List<IDAO<IBusinessObject>>(); // add type parameter for IDAO
   daoList.Add(new BankAccountDAO());
   daoList.Add(new CategoryDAO());
   public void myMethod(IBusinessObject b) // has to be IBusinessObject; 
                                           //you'll need to cast the underlying 
                                       ///type to promote it to a BankAccount or Category.
   {
      daoList.ElementAt(0).Save(b); // this should call the implemented Save() method of BankAccountDao
   }
}
```